# Selecting minimum value and remove maximum

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a text file having data like

```
EASSDS.txt 2738
EQQSDS7M.txt 394
EOG66.txt 354
EASSDS.txt 292
EQQSDS7M.txt 301
```

I want that it should only select the minimum and delete the maximum 
`Output.txt`

```
EOG66.txt 354
EASSDS.txt 292
EQQSDS7M.txt 301
```

If it found the duplicate it only select the question with minimum value like i show in the output and input

Below is the code i tried

```
with open('input.txt') as nums:
    lines = re.findall(r'\w+\.txt\s+\d+', nums.read())

numbers = {}
for line in lines:
    line_split = re.split(r'\.txt\s+', line)
    count = line_split[1]
    numbers[line_split[0]] = int(line_split[1])
```

Comment: Do you really need to use regex here?

Comment: @SukritKalra nope, pretty sure my answer does it without.

Comment: @SukritKalra Its my opinion , may be its wrong or may be its a bad way , thats why i post here , if you have better answer or code than i welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just use a simple approach using `defaultdict` here.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> m = defaultdict(list)
>>> with open('testFile.txt' ,'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            name, val = line.split()
            m[name].append(val)
>>> m
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'EOG66.txt': ['354'], 'EASSDS.txt': ['2738', '292'], 'EQQSDS7M.txt': ['394', '301']})
>>> with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
        for elem in m:
            f.write("{} {}\n".format(elem, min(map(int, m[elem]))))
```

Which gave me an output like

```
EOG66.txt 354
EASSDS.txt 292
EQQSDS7M.txt 301
```

Comment: I believe OP was looking to delete any values above the minimum, but if there's no issue in holding onto them, great answer.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus : Yeah, well it does kinda depends on how much data he has in the input file. :)

Answer (score 2):

You're nearly there, but keep in mind that you need some branching logic here in case you've already indexed the number, like so:

```
number = {}
for line in lines:
    split_line = line.split()
    if numbers.get(split_line[0], False):
        numbers[split_line[0]] = min(numbers[split_line[0]], int(split_line[1]))
    else:
        numbers[split_line[0]] = int(split_line[1])
```

Additionally, correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems that your values always have a space between them, so you don't quite need to bust out the regex split hammer, and less regex is always good. Let me know if this breaks on something in your test set though.

Comment: Yes , text file has space every time , between the value and the file , like `ERWEFA.txt 233`